# Additional device "Nexus 7" in list of my devices

Tags: nexus-7

I went to list of my devices and I see always one non my device "Nexus 7".
It was strange, I immediately changed password and activated verifying with using mobile phone.

After that I login with my devices and Nexus 7 appeared again.

I made some investigations and I found that Nexus 7 appear only when I login on my tablet "Pipo M6". (Pipo M6 device also is in list of devices). Time (the last login) is a little different between Nexus 7 and Pipo M6.

It's a little strange, could you please explain me why I see this additional device.

It is possible that this situation related with SuperSU or other applications, which have root access ?

Comment: I think you may have malware on your Pipo tablet. Logout from tablet. Change password, delete from list Nexus and Pipo, finally per few days don't login on your tablet to make sure you're right ;-)

Comment: Start thinking on root your device and install CM http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/82431-pipo-m6-pro/

Comment: @piotrek1543 I already did these actions. Only after I login on my pipo appears Nexus,

Comment: like i said you need to clean your android device. Check for popular Malware clean software for Android or root and install on it custom ROM like CyanogenMod

Comment: Ok, I will check malware.

Comment: Just to get the facts. Where is it that your seeing the "nexus 7"? Is it on the PC, Google account, WiFi network, or ???? There could be many reasons. We need further details, speculation isn't going to help fix your dilemma.